# Template function to receive a generic map as a parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, stdmap, template-templates

There may be many case in which we want to perform some operation on a `std::map` or a `std::unordered_map` that is exactly the same, independently from the type of the map. Let us consider the following example:

```
#include <map>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <iostream>

template< template <typename,typename> class Container >
void printMap(Container<int, long> inputMap, bool additionalParam = false)
{
    for (const pair<int,long> p : inputMap)
        cout<<p.first <<","<< p.second <<std::endl;
}

int main()
{
int a = 1;
long b = 2;
map<int,long> map1;
map1.emplace(a,b);
unordered_map<int,long> map2;
map2.emplace(a,b);
printMap(map1);
printMap(map2);

return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

If I try to compile the example above, I have this:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘printMap(std::map<int, long int>&)’
```

I read about the use of template of template in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/406936/2110769). What is the right way to do that?

Comment: A [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) has more than two template parameters.  You also have a type `Compare` and a type `Allocator`.  You have to specify all, even the defaulted ones.

Comment: Note that your code will just work come C++17; the solutions below are all for C++14 and below.

Answer (score 5):

Try with

```
template< template <typename...> class Container, typename ... Ts >
void printMap(Container<int, long, Ts...> inputMap,
              bool additionalParam = false)
```

The (bigger) problem in your code is that `std::map` and `std::unordered_map` are template classes with four (not two) template parameters. The 3rd and the 4th have default value so you can define a `std::map` object as

```
 std::map<int, long> map1;
```

but, with default parameter, you're defining it as

```
 std::map<int, long, std::less<int>,
          std::allocator<std::pair<const int, long> >> map1;
```

(ps: or you can make it simple and use `auto`, as in the Semyon Burov's solution; +1)

Answer (score 5):

Compiler cant deduce template argument if you define it that way.
Try to use:

```
template<typename Map>
void printMap(const Map& map, bool additionalParam = false) {
    for (const auto& p : map)
        cout<<p.first <<","<< p.second <<std::endl;
}
```

If you need to check, that `Map` is exactly `Map<int, long int>`, then add static assertion to a body of function:

```
static_assert( std::is_same< typename Map::key_type, int >::value &&
                       std::is_same< typename Map::mapped_type, long >::value, "!");
```

Comment: I added a `static_assert` to maintain the type constraints.

Comment: @HenriMenke Personally, I dont see any problem in ability to print any kind of map instead of `Map<int, long int>`.

Comment: Me neither, but it was part of the question that the map is specialized for `int` and `long`.

Comment: Not a great difference but the test proposed by Henri Menke can be used also to enable/disable (via SFINAE) the function; something like `template <typename Map> typename std::enable_if<std::is_same< typename Map::key_type, int >::value && std::is_same< typename Map::mapped_type, long >::value>::type printMap(const Map& map, bool additionalParam = false)`

Comment: Come on... Even if a type of key and value of a map is valueable for topic starter, the assertion definitely shouldn't be in printing function. May be somewhere else, where there are actual work with elements of map. `printMap` functionality is limited only by existence of `operator<<` overload for key and value types of map

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
template<class Container>
void printMap(const Container& inputMap)
{
    using Key = typename Container::key_type; 
    using Value = typename Container::mapped_type;
    for (const std::pair<Key,Value> p : inputMap)
        std::cout << p.first << "," << p.second << std::endl;
}
```

or better yet, just:

```
template<class Container>
void printMap(const Container& inputMap)
{
    for (const auto& p : inputMap)
        std::cout << p.first << ","<< p.second << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: @EdgarRokyan: Oh, yeah, that's fine, I was just kinda illustrating the point. But, yeah.